# I am trying to connect a second monitor to a computer with only a 9 point 10101 A port

Tags: windows-10

I have 9 point connection on my computer and am trying to do a double monitor. The 9 point says 10101 A. Is there a connector for this to an HP2009m Monitor?

Comment: @Tetsujin It is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the port you're referring to is a RS-323 port (Serial Port). This port was used for serial communication back before USB existed (For connecting a mouse and that sort of things). The 10101 label on the port is just a string of ones and zeros (Serial communication).
This port doesn't output a video signal, so you can't hook up a monitor to it.
If you want to connect a monitor to your computer, you should look for a VGA, DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort port on your computer. If there aren't any or they are all occupied, you can buy a video card and install it on one of your PCIe slots.